# Why StreamWriter can't write text into file in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#, and I'm writing a some text into a file, for this purpose, I'm using a source code which I found searching on Google:

```
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Server.MapPath("~/FILE/") + logFile);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

//sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " sent email to " + email);
sw.Write(" sent email to " );

fs.Close();
```

This code runs, but when I open text file, I can't see any data in it, what is happening? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx and https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+write+text+file

Comment: Try closing `sw` first to make sure it flushes what you wrote before you close `fs`  or better yet put both into [`using` statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: @juharr I suppose the writer would automatically also close the undrlying stream.

Comment: @HimBromBeere In this case yes, but it is possible to tell the writer to leave the stream open when you create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code as below. hope you are looking for this kind.

```
 using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Server.MapPath("~/FILE/") + logFile))
 {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        //sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " sent email to " + email);
        sw.Write(" sent email to ");
    }
    fs.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple `File.AppendAllText`

```
File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FILE/"), logFile),
  string.Format("{0} sent email to {1}", DateTime.Now, email));
```

to append the log file instead using streams and writers.

Comment: thanks,is the has way to solve my code?i want write with that code.

Comment: @behi behi: if your goal is just to append the log file, then `File.AppendAllText` will do it for you (open streams, writers, then close tem in a proper way). `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` just bring complexity to your code. Streams and writers are the way when you have to implement a complex code with conditions, erase, overwrite etc.

Comment: thanks my friend,your right ,but in my company ,my boss say just write with that!.